# MySQL error #1054 unknown column in field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (paypal_transaction.buyerId) ) AS cid FROM eg_posts_details
INNER JOIN paypal_transaction ON paypal_transaction.id =  eg_posts_details.OrderId
WHERE seller_id =190
```

It runs perfectly on MySQL directly but when I run it from my PHP codeigniter model I get the #1054 error. I have no idea why this is happening. Please help.

Here is the PHP code:

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (paypal_transaction.buyerId) ) AS cid 
FROM eg_posts_details 
INNER JOIN paypal_transaction ON paypal_transaction.id =  eg_posts_details.OrderId 
WHERE seller_id =190");
```

Comment: How are you processing the result? The problem lies there

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by processing the result. can you please explain a bit?

Comment: When do you get the unknown column error? Are you referring different column name in later part of the php code?

Comment: specify table name before your id , `tbl_name.seller_id`

Comment: use echo $this->db->last_query() to debug. Check if the query is the same.

Comment: This is what I get: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'paypal_transaction.buyerId' in 'field list'

`SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ( paypal_transaction.buyerId ) ) AS cid FROM eg_posts_details INNER JOIN paypal_transaction ON paypal_transaction.id = eg_posts_details.OrderId WHERE seller_id =190`

Comment: Hanann Ashraf, this doesn't work.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is NOT a function. `COUNT( DISTINCT ( paypal_transaction.buyerId ) )` is the same as `COUNT( DISTINCT paypal_transaction.buyerId )`, those extra parentheses makes no sense!!! (You can even do `COUNT( DISTINCT (( paypal_transaction.buyerId )) )`, still no function...

Comment: jarlh, I've removed the extra parenthesis but the result is the same.

Comment: You sure buyerId exist in your table ? Looking at your other columns, they are named with lower case and underscore.

Comment: frz3993, it does exit. See the schema screenshot for paypal_transaction table: http://oi63.tinypic.com/esvm8w.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As per your image reference, paypal transaction table contain buyerId and you used it as buyer_id. So use the following.
Use like this

```
$sql = "select count(distinct(`paypal_transaction`.`buyerId`)) as `cid` from `eg_posts_details` inner join `paypal_transaction` on `paypal_transaction`.`id` = `eg_posts_details`.`OrderId` where `seller_id`= '190' ";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Hope its work for you

Comment: yes it is. Actually the problem is he misspelled the column name located in paypal_transaction table